# pygame gives an error when calling update

Tags: pygame

I am trying to run some tutorial code on pygame. But when pygame.update I get error: , and nothing else just error: and then python exits.

```
import pygame         
pygame.init()
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_caption('test')
clock=pygame.time.Clock()
crashed= False

while not crashed:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        crashed = True
      print(event)
    pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created a window/screen yet, so there's nothing to update.

Put this before your loop and after init:

`screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) # or whatnot`

Also you have some indention errors, but given that this is running I'm assuming that's a typo while indenting the code into the post.

Also, for future reference, it helps people answer faster if you include the actual error message including stack trace.

Comment: I did include error message, it was literal 'error:', and the trace back only showed ---> 15     pygame.display.update(), and a few  lines before the code.